# Spark: some general best practices for generic "out of memory" errors?

Tags: apache-spark

I use time to time Spark that I consider a really great solution for my data processing. However sometimes I get "out of memory" errors not always easy to spot just looking at logs. Is there any general good approach to find and fix those issues? What I read as suggested solutions are tweaking parameters here and there. It sounds to me like to attempt the luck.

Answer (score 1):

- Avoid GroupByKey
- Don't copy all elements of a large RDD to the driver
- Gracefully Dealing with Bad Input Data
- When Spark is transferring data over the network, it needs to serialize objects into a binary form. This can have an effect on performance when shuffling or on other operations that require large amounts of data to be transferred. To ameliorate this, first try to make sure that your code is written in a way that minimizes the amount of shuffling that may occur (e.g. only use groupByKey as a last resort, preferring instead to use actions like reduceByKey which perform aggregation as in-place as possible). Second, consider
  using Kryo instead of java.io.Serializable for your objects, as it has a more compact
  binary representation than the standard Java serializer, and is also faster to compress or decompress. For further performance, especially when dealing with billions of objects, you can register classes with the Kryo serializer at start-up, saving more precious bytes.
- With larger datasets (>200Gb), garbage collection on the JVM Spark runs may become a performance issue. In general, switching to the G1 GC over the default ParallelGC will ultimately be more performant. Although, some tuning will be required according to the details of your dataset and application.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above,

1. Manage the executor memory based on input size
2. You can use disk and memory option, when the input size don't fit in memory